# How to update text in Unity UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to display a string of text in Unity that updates to display a log of what's happening. Right now the code I have doesn't have any errors and loads the initial message, but doesn't update.

I do have the text linked to the script in Unity, so that isn't the problem.

At the beginning I declare Text UserUpdate and a string to use as a container for the text.

```
public Text UserUpdate;
public string userUpdate;
```

In start I assign it a value (This works so far).

```
public void Start()
{
    userUpdate = "Create an account or login";
}
```

Later I call functions and use conditions to change the value of userUpdate

```
public void LoginButtonPressed()
{
    FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(EmailAddress.text, Password.text).
        ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Login was cancelled");
                userUpdate = "Login was cancelled";
                return;
            }

            if(task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Error logging in");
                userUpdate = "Error logging in";
                return;
            }

            if(task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Usermanager: User signed in successfully: {0}", EmailAddress.text);
                userUpdate = "Sign in successful";
                isLoadMainScene = true;
            }


        });

}
```

Then under void Update() I assign the value of UserUpdate.text

```
void Update()
{
    UserUpdate.text = userUpdate;
}
```

Comment: I think you should refactor this to [use a Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). [Here is an example updating the UI.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/814282/trouble-updating-ui-asynchronously.html)

Comment: Put `Debug.Log(UserUpdate.text)` in the `Update` unction and see if you get anything in the Console tab. By the way, do you see the `Debug.LogError` logs in your `LoginButtonPressed` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were there no errors from `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync`? Maybe the callback is not getting invoked so there is nothing assigning the value to userUpdate.

Also instead of always assigning the value of UserUpdate.text in Update, you can just put that inside `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` callback or have a Property to set the value of UserUpdate.text whenever you are setting the value of userUpdate.

```
public string UserUpdateProperty
{
    get
    {
        return userUpdate;
    }
    set
    {
        userUpdate = value;
        UpdateUser.text = userUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer by far

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnGUI(){

GUI.Label(new Rect(0,0,0,0),userUpdate);
}
```

add this method, adjust the rect to the same settings as your text on your canvas. delete your text. this will work.

ive also had good luck with TMP, go to your scene and click add- 3d- TextMeshPro, and name it whatever like 'texty' then you can do `texty.Text=`

if you want it to work as is, put this in your `Awake()`

`UserUpdate = GetComponent<Text>();`

but this will only work if the text is attached to the same object as this script